# Changes in prefix/ASN (Autonomous System Number) pairs?

Tags: network-topology, network-analysis

I am wondering if a pair prefix/AS may change often ? 
I mean let's say we have a list with many given prefixes (e.g. 4.6.20.0/24) that are mapped to ASN (e.g. 10753), this list is built on a given date. The question is, should we expect that several prefixes are mapped to other ASN in a list built few days later ?

I am asking this question because I m using a tool (pyasn) to perform ip to ASN lookup with historical data. It is possible (using RIB file from RouteView) to create lists of prefixes/AS pairs every 2 or 3 hours. I wonder if it is necessary to be that precise since the creation of the list is relatively costly ?

I personally do not think these pairs are meant to be changed often, but I d like a confirmation, and if possible a link towards a document that I can cite as reference in my work ? I have searched during half an hour without success ...

Thank you all in advance :D

Comment: I'm not sure this is quite on topic here, since it seems to be about the history of some particular network protocols.

Comment: Being a programmer, I usually post on stack overflow, and I thought it was of topic to be posted there, I checked the list of all the exhange sites and I thought this one was the most appropriate :/ Where should I ask then ?

Comment: Let's see what other people say.

Comment: Looks on-topic for ServerFault. This is bookkeeping and not science.

Comment: I m not using it for a server, it s about general purpose information, should i still post it there ?

Comment: Why don't you try using your tool to perform lookups frequently for a little while, and measure how commonly they change?  Data will probably trump any guesses we might give.  Note that not all questions have a home somewhere on the Stack Exchange network, so there might not be any place to post.  If you do post on another site, please delete this copy first, so you don't have two copies open on two different sites simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you for your attention and reply, I could have measured it myself it is true, but I was simply in the hurry. I ll leave this post here and keep you update if I find anything